# Error: Connection refused for MQTT Mosquitto on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have to install MQTT Broker Mosquitto on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. The port 1883 is opened via console, but I am still getting the error:

```
Error: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://community.openenergymonitor.org/t/mqtt-error-connection-refused/4264/2), you need to run `mosquitto` as a daemon by running:

```
mosquitto -d
```

To have it start at boot time, you can enable the `mosquitto` service by running:

```
sudo systemctl enable mosquitto.service
```